# nineoldandroids exception util

Tags: android, nineoldandroids

I am having an issue using nineoldandroids. My Logcat is:

```
06-17 18:46:59.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1576): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 18:46:59.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1576): java.lang.StackOverflowError
06-17 18:46:59.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at com.nineoldandroids.util.IntProperty.set(IntProperty.java:43)
06-17 18:46:59.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at com.nineoldandroids.util.IntProperty.set(IntProperty.java:43)
06-17 18:46:59.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at com.nineoldandroids.util.IntProperty.set(IntProperty.java:43)
```

and my code is:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator= ObjectAnimator.ofInt(miscrol, "scrollY", 0, 480).setDuration(duration);
                    objectAnimator.start();

                }
            });
```

What I am doing wrong? thank you.

Comment: You should have a loop in your code that is calling a method too much time. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: I only have an AsyncTask to get the values of web service. The animation I do to an Scrollview, is it possible or I have to change? thanks

Comment: Add an `@Override` annotation before your `onClick` method. It might not change anything but it is worth to test it.

Comment: no, not change anything :(

Comment: I don't know why you get this error. But you can use the `smoothScrollBy()` method on your `scrollView` to make it scroll by a specific position. It will be easier than using an `ObjectAnimator`.